# Should I use "IF" for mysqli $stmt prepare

Tags: mysqli

I have been using prepared statements with "IF" and without "IF", is there any difference?  example;

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare) {}
```

and

```
$stmt1=$mysqli->prepare;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no body to your `if` statement, then no, there is no difference.

Comment: Got it!  Seen it both ways.  Thanks